# Automorphisms countable set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

I am stucked with the following exercise from an elementary set theory course. Any help, even just a small advice on how to start, would be appreciated.

> Let $(S,<)$ be a total order and suppose $S$ to be a countable set. If
> the cardinality of the  automorphisms of $(S,<)$ is more than
> countable, prove that then it is exactly $2^{\aleph_0}$. This is of
> course without assuming CH.

**I edited the orginal post by writing the correct hypothesis, namely $\vert \operatorname{Aut}(S) \vert>\aleph_0$.**

Comment: Are you sure you've copied the problem correctly? I would expect the assumption to be that $\vert\mathsf{Aut}(S)\vert{\color{red}{>}}\aleph_0$ instead.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you are right, thanks, I made a mistake. I edited the post.

Comment: It obviously can't be more than the continuum, since $\vert \Bbb N^{\Bbb N} \vert = 2^{\aleph_0}$ and $\operatorname{Aut} \subseteq S^S$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edited post is correct, and is an instance of the "definable continuum hypothesis" theme common in descriptive set theory.

Fixing a bijection between the (underlying set of the) linear order $\mathcal{S}=(S;\le)$ in question and the natural numbers, the set of automorphisms of $\mathcal{S}$ can be reconstrued as a set of points in Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$. Being injective and order-preserving are each **closed** properties, and surjectivity is a $G_\delta$ property, so the set of (sequences corresponding to) automorphisms is $G_\delta$. Now use the fact that every uncountable $G_\delta$ set has size continuum.

In case you haven't proved that fact already, here's the general strategy:

> Suppose we have open sets $U_i\subseteq\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ ($i\in\mathbb{N}$) such that $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}U_i$ is uncountable. Recursively build a function $$\rho: 2^{<\mathbb{N}}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}^{<\mathbb{N}}$$ such that $(i)$ $\rho$ is prefix-order-preserving and injective, and $(ii)$ for every finite string $\sigma$, every infinite $f\succ\rho(\sigma)$ lies in $U_i$ for every $i<\vert\sigma\vert$. You'll use uncountability to ensure that this can actually be done, and then "applying $\rho$ to the infinite binary sequences" gives an explicit size-continuum subset of $\bigcap_{i\in\mathbb{N}}U_i$.

In fact a more advanced analogue of this ("unfolding" - see [Kechris, *Classical descriptive set theory*, chapter II.21.B](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-4190-4)) applies to arbitrary **analytic** sets, but that goes a bit far afield.

Answer (score 6):

This is false (as originally written) because $\Bbb Z$ has only countably many order-automorphisms.

For any $n \in \Bbb Z, \varphi_n:  k \mapsto k+n$ is an order-automorphism.

However, because an order-automorphism must preserve successors and predecessors and every element of $\Bbb Z$ is both a successor and a predecessor that can be "reached" from $0$ in finitely many steps, it's easy to prove by induction on $\vert k \vert$ that any automorphism $\varphi$ of $\Bbb Z$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi(0)$.  Thus, each order-automorphism of $\Bbb Z$ is of the form $\varphi_n$ for some $n \in \Bbb Z$.

Comment: Another way to show that $\varphi$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi(0)$ is that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, if there is a $c \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{n,n+1\}$ with $\varphi(n) < c  < \varphi(n+1)$ then as $\varphi$ is an automorphism, we must have $n < \varphi^{-1}(c) < n+1$, which is absurd. And so successive numbers are mapped to successive numbers.